# Hyperlink text of one string in angular in the template

Tags: angular, templates, components

I have this string in angular component:

```
...
value="Click <a href='/something'>here</a>";
...
```

in html I have:

```
...
<div>
  {{value}}
</div>
...
```

I whould like to see in the page as a word link like: Click here.

instead that I see Click here as text.

I need this because i am customizing an alert dialog as modal.

is it `possible to see as html link the value text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use a value with tags in your template, Angular recognizes it as unsafe, so it sanitizes the value directly. You need to bind your value to the innerHTML attribute of your div. [Angular doc](https://angular.io/guide/security#sanitization-example)

So in your case do it like this

```
...
<div [innerHTML]="value">
</div>
...
```